# asp.net mvc restsharp api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, restsharp

```
   // GET: GetLogApi
    public ActionResult Index(GetItems getItems, int? PageIndex)
    {
        getItems.PageIndex = PageIndex;
        string uri = string.Format("https://log.egeyazilim.net/api/v1/Logger/Get?logType={0}&logAction={1}&applicationType={2}&clientType={3}&companyCode={4}&comment={5}&applicationModule={6}&method={7}&=ipAddress{8}&url={9}&statusCode={10}&isError={11}&requestedOnUtc={12}&responsedOnUtc={13}&isActive={14}&PageIndex={15}&Limit={16}",
          getItems.LogType ?? "",
          getItems.LogAction ?? "",
          getItems.ApplicationType ?? "",
          getItems.ClientType ?? "",
          getItems.CompanyCode ?? "",
          getItems.Comment ?? "",
          getItems.ApplicationModule ?? "",
          getItems.Method ?? "",
          getItems.IpAddress ?? "",
          getItems.Url ?? "",
          getItems.ResponseStatus ?? "",
          getItems.IsError ? "Checked" : "",
          getItems.StartDate ?? "",
          getItems.EndDate ?? "",
          getItems.isActive ? "Checked" : "",
          getItems.PageIndex ?? 1,
          50);
        var restClient = new RestClient(uri);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("X-Api-Key", "C5BFF7F0-B4DF-475E-A331-F737424F013C");

        List<LogInfoGet> logInfoGet = new List<LogInfoGet>();
        GenericReturn<List<LogInfoGet>> genericReturn = new GenericReturn<List<LogInfoGet>>();

        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        IRestResponse response = restClient.Execute<LogInfoGet>(request);

        var requestModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LogInfoGet>(response.Content);

        return View(requestModel);

    }
```

public class LogInfoGet{

```
    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public Item[] Items { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("currentPageIndex")]
    public long CurrentPageIndex { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("totalItemsCount")]
    public long TotalItemsCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("filteredItemsCount")]
    public long FilteredItemsCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("displayedItemsCount")]
    public long DisplayedItemsCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("totalPages")]
    public long TotalPages { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("hasPreviousPage")]
    public bool HasPreviousPage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("hasNextPage")]
    public bool HasNextPage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("nextPage")]
    public Uri NextPage { get; set; }
}

public partial class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("logType")]
    public string LogType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("logAction")]
    public string LogAction { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("applicationType")]
    public string ApplicationType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("clientType")]
    public string ClientType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("applicationModule")]
    public string ApplicationModule { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("companyCode")]
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("comment")]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("requestedOnUtc")]
    public DateTimeOffset RequestedOnUtc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("responsedOnUtc")]
    public DateTimeOffset ResponsedOnUtc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("request")]
    public Request Request { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public Response Response { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("entityId")]
    public string EntityId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("objectId")]
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("createdOnUtc")]
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedOnUtc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isActive")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public partial class Request
{
    [JsonProperty("method")]
    public string Method { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isHttps")]
    public bool IsHttps { get; set; }
}

public partial class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("statusCode")]
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isError")]
    public bool IsError { get; set; }
}
```

}

But I want to send this as a querystring I don't want to send it from the string in url and I edited the code like this

```
    public ActionResult Index(GetItems getItems, int? PageIndex)
    {
        getItems.PageIndex = PageIndex;
        string uri = string.Format("https://log.egeyazilim.net");
        var restClient = new RestClient(uri);
        var request = new RestRequest("/api/v1/Logger/Get", Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("X-Api-Key", "C5BFF7F0-B4DF-475E-A331-F737424F013C");
        request.AddParameter("LogType", getItems.LogType ?? "", ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddParameter("LogAction", getItems.LogAction ?? "", ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddParameter("ApplicationType", getItems.ApplicationType ?? "", ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddParameter("ClientType", getItems.ClientType ?? "", ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddParameter("CompanyCode", getItems.CompanyCode ?? "", ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddParameter("ApplicationModule", getItems.ApplicationModule ?? "", ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddParameter("Method", getItems.Method ?? "", ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddParameter("IpAddress", getItems.IpAddress ?? "", ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddParameter("Url", getItems.Url ?? "", ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddParameter("StatusCode", getItems.ResponseStatus ?? "", ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddParameter("IsError", getItems.IsError, ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddParameter("RequestedOnUtc", getItems.StartDate ?? "", ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddParameter("ResponsedOnUtc", getItems.EndDate ?? "", ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddParameter("IsActive", getItems.isActive, ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddParameter("PageIndex", getItems.PageIndex ?? 1, ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddParameter("Limit", getItems.Limit ?? 50, ParameterType.QueryString);

        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        IRestResponse response = restClient.Execute<LogInfoGet>(request);

        var requestModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LogInfoGet>(response.Content);
        //request.AddJsonBody(requestModel);
        //logInfoGet.AddRange(requestModel.);
        //genericReturn.ReturnObject = new List<LogInfoGet>();
        //genericReturn.ReturnObject.AddRange();
        return View(requestModel);


    }
```

I can get Items [] array seamlessly from the first line of code. But in the second block of code, PageIndex etc. Values like, but Items [] becomes Null. I would be glad if you could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the typed `Execute<T>` method, you instruct RestSharp to deserialize for you. So the call to `DeserializeObject` makes no sense, you use one or another.

If you want RestSharp to do the serialization work, you might get into a struggle when using the default serializer (SumnpleJson) because, well, it's simple and is not that comprehensive as, for example, Json.NET.

If you get the correct response (so the `response.Content` looks legit) but you get empty data, the easiest way is to use another serializer. I see you already prepared your response model for Newtonsoft.Json. Why not just use it then? It's [properly documented](https://restsharp.dev/usage/serialization.html#newtonsoftjson-aka-json-net), just a line of code to add.

```
client.UseNewtonsoftJson();
```

One more thing - it's never a good idea to instantiate `RestClient` repeatedly. Make it a singleton.